# How can we know what kind of a constraint was dropped in Sql Server without maintaining our own copy of sys.objects?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, triggers, constraints, ddl

So, I created the following DDL trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [BeforeAlterTable] ON DATABASE FOR ALTER_TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE Name = 'PK_MyTable'
END
```

The problem is that when `PK_MyTable` primary key is dropped, the trigger outputs empty result set - the information about the primary key is already gone from the sys.objects view.

This could be resolved by maintaining our own copy of sys.objects (a subset of type = 'PK' would suffice), but I would like to avoid it.

Anyway to make it work?

**EDIT 1**

Note that the question is about deducing the kind of the constraint, not its name or the table it belongs too. These are found in the EVENTDATA() function result. What is not found there is the kind of the constraint.

Comment: "Information about an event that fires a DDL trigger is captured by using the EVENTDATA function." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-eventdata-function

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/

Comment: I am specifically asking about the constraint **KIND**. I know I can have the table and the constraint name in the EVENTDATA function. I will refine the post to emphasise it.